# SpringBoot: Autowired works in Configuration, but returns null in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**My Problem:** I have created a Singleton Bean of my model Manager. Trying to Autowire it in my Controller, however, results in a nullpointer. In my configuration, however, the Autowiring of the same Bean works just fine.

I should note at this point that this is not the first singleton Bean I have made in this project; and as far as I can tell, I have made it in the same vein as all the others; which all Autowire correctly. That's the main reason why I'm stumped right now.

**The Code:**

The Main App is under the 'project' package, so all other packages are sub-packages of that one.
I opted to omit the imports for brevity, but everything is imported as it should be.

Config

```
package project.config

@Configuration
public class BootstrapConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    public ThingManager thingManager() {
        return new thingManager();
    }

   @Autowired
   private ThingManager manager;


   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize() {
     manager.setup() //This works fine.

  }
}
```

Manager

```
package project.model

public class ThingManager {

   private HashMap<String, Thing> things;

   public ThingManager() {
     things = new HashMap<String, Thing>();
   }

   public void setup() {
     //Do setup Things
   }

   public Thing getThing(String input) {
     return things.get(input);
   }

}
```

Controller

```
package project.controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/things")
public class ThingController {

  @Autowired
  ThingManager manager; //This is null

  private Thing thing;

  public ThingController() {
    this.thing = manager.getThing("test"); //This then throws NullPointer.
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public ResponseEntity<Thing> showThing() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(thing);
  }
}
```

**What I have tried:**
I have tried marking ThingManager as `@Component @Scope(value = "singleton")`instead of setting up the Bean manually (so I removed the `@Bean` code-block in the configuration); the result is the same; Configuration can Autowire it perfectly fine, but Controller cannot.

I have looked at the myriad of posts about this topic already on here, but most seem to be about someone having forgotten to mark the class they Autowire in as a component or similar. Maybe I overlooked a similarity to my problem; it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring can autowire fields only after the object is created (the constructor is called), so you're accessing the `manager` in the constructor of ThingControler while it's not yet injected.  The easiest way to use `manager` in the constructor would be to add it as a constructor parameter instead of autowiring (Spring will use available bean for the parameter):

```
// ... 
public class ThingController {

  private final Thing thing;

  public ThingController(ThingManager manager) {
    this.thing = manager.getThing("test");
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Good to know; that did it. Thanks. :)